# OpenCV: How to get the bounding box for each contour?

Tags: c++, opencv

** ~ Updated ~ ** 
Hi , I have a source file and i converted it to below picture , and i have a contour in my program

[image]

```
void find_contour(int, void*, Mat _mat)
{
    Mat edge_detect_canny;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(_mat, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(_mat.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 1, 8, hierarchy, 1, Point());
        }
    IMshow(drawing, "draw-Res", 0);
    imwrite("c:\\draw.bmp", drawing);
    int cs = contours.size();
    cout << cs << "contour.size" << endl;
}
```

that works fine but i want to add bounding box,find the bounding box for each contour to select all of my objects.
What should I do?

Comment: @Miki   hi , good job , i try this example [link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html)  , but not working  i'm beginner in opencv , what should i do ? regards .

Comment: Please post the code you tried into the question, as well as the input image

Comment: @Miki: I update the post :)

Comment: Just add in your for loop: `Rect box = boundingRect(contours[i]); rectangle(drawing, box, color);`

Comment: @Miki : thanks a lot Works fine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the bounding box for each contour as:

```
Rect box = boundingRect(contours[i]);
```

and you can draw it as:

```
rectangle(drawing, box, color);
```

So simply add these two lines in the `for` loop:

```
Rect box = boundingRect(contours[i]); 
rectangle(drawing, box, color);
```

Comment: Any Idea on how to reverse it? Like I have Array of bounding rectangles. How can I convert them to contours?

Comment: @ArunGowda, you can convert the image to binary using cv2.threshold and then whiteout the rectangle you have as you already have their coordinates and then you can use cv2.findContours function to get their contours. There must be an easy as well but this is all I can think of.